# Keep overlapping of DIVs when only one is floated

Tags: html, position, overlap

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#side {
width: 250px;
float: left;
height: 400px;
background: #CCC;
}

#main {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 600px;
background: #000;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="side"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

A very basic example. When I resize the browser window, the #side element will overlap #main if it gets small enough. How can I keep this layout but have #side stay as the very left element with #main resting against it as the browser gets smaller?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/WaDp6/

Comment: That's what I originally tried, but then the #main element is no longer directly in the middle @ full-sized browser width, it's floating to the left of the side

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want ?

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width:1100px;
}

#side {
width: 250px;
float: left;
height: 400px;
background: #CCC;
}

#main {
width: 800px;
float:left;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 600px;
background: #000;
}
-->
</style>
```

Comment: That's what I originally tried, but then the #main element is no longer directly in the middle @ full-sized browser width, it's floating to the left of the side

Comment: you will have to use jquery/javascript because it concerns resizing